# contao isotope image size etc

Tags: image, product, image-size, contao

i've got a problem regarding the image size in the productoverview in isotope, when i upload an image to a product and then watch it back on the page the image is covering the whole page.
now i tried to make it smaller by going to : store configuration > galleries but the only thing that gets smaller is the watermark, like its just ignoring the productimage...

i would upload some screenshots but i can't because of the whole reputation thingy on stackoverflow.

i hope to get an answer soon.